# How to check time elapsed and allocated memory in C++?

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a program C++ that performs on a single thread.

### Allocated Memory ?

How to check the amount of memory allocated by this program like for example using a function that returns the number of bytes allocated to this (single-threaded) program at a given instance of execution.

```
.
.
.
std::cout << memoryallocated() << endl;
.
.
```

### Time Elapsed ?

And what is the most precise way to calculate the time (in milisecs for example) elapsed executing a set of instructions ?

Comment: a wild [Cross-Platform Memory Leak Detector](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm) appears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard C++ interface (or C interface) for knowing either of time or memory usage of an application. There may be interfaces for a specific OS to find out the memory usage - for example, in Linux, you can read `/proc/$PID/status` and look for `VmSize` to find out the size of the current process in total. Other OS's have various other techniques.

There are typically a `clock` function in the standard C runtime, which will give fairly precise timing - but the time measured depends on the system - sometimes it's CPU time (Linux and other Unix varieties, for example) and sometimes it's elapsed time (Windows for example).

There are a variety of C++11 time keeping functions that will be able to give you wall time. The [`std::chrono`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) functionality will help with this. For short duratins, [`high_resolution_clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/) can be quite useful.

This `steady_clock` reference gives an [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/steady_clock) of how the `chrono` functionality can be used.

Of course, if you just want to see the total memory for a Unix/Linux process, you can use `/usr/bin/time -v some-prog` - that will show all manner of statistics, including memory usage, CPU time, percentage CPU time, etc.